# Should the CSS cursor property be set on the element itself, or on its :hover pseudo-class?

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a cursor: pointer property on an element.

```
.element {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This would work, but so would

```
.element:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Which one is semantically correct ? I can't see how the cursor property would ever be useful outside of a hover event.

Comment: Not sure where semantics come into it.

Comment: This seems opinion-based. I usually set it on the element itself tho.

Comment: on the element itself you would just save a few bytes for each rule

Comment: Perhaps one argument for setting it via the non-hover selector already: Some mobile devices/browsers show hover styles on the first tap, and require a second tap to actually interact with the element, if `:hover` styles are set. So if you don’t have any other hover effect for the element, and you would be using `.element:hover` to specify the cursor _only_ – then I’d say it probably makes more sense to specify the cursor via `.element {…}` only, so that mobile devices don’t require a second tap.

Comment: If it helps, browsers like Firefox apply `cursor: pointer` to the anchor tag by default (not :hover state)

Comment: @CBroe Mobile devices usually don't show cursors.

Comment: @marsze: You don’t say :) My point was, _any_ rules with `:hover` can trigger this two-taps-instead-of-one behavior AFAIK. So the user would tap once, for the hover styles to get applied (which they won’t even see anything of, _because_ mobile doesn’t display cursors), and needed to tap a second time to activate the element.

Comment: @CBroe This is not relevant to the question. It's specific to the `cursor` property, because it kind of "implies" a `:hover` by default.

Comment: You’re just not getting my point …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are "semantically" / technically correct. But happen to have the same effect in this case. I don't know why one would choose to utilize a pseudo class for it. Unless you want to change the pointer at `:active` only for instance.